# How to add sum value text above the Percentage stacked bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Dear StackOverFlow Leaders,

I have drawn a Percentages based stacked bar chart, and I am trying to add the total number of actual sums i.e. not percentages on top of the bar chart, and I could not figure out how. Any advice/help is appreciated.

On the top of bar charts, I want to display actual sums i.e "Total Fruit Count = 464" , "Total Fruit Count = 326", "Total Fruit Count = 77" for March , April and May months respectively.

Here is my data table ,

```
YearMonth       Fruit   Frequency       Percentage
2021_05_May     Apple   46      59.74025974
2021_05_May     Mango   21      27.27272727
2021_05_May     Kiwi    10      12.98701299
2021_04_Apr     Apple   126     38.65030675
2021_04_Apr     Mango   50      15.33742331
2021_04_Apr     Kiwi    150     46.01226994
2021_03_Mar     Apple   95      20.47413793
2021_03_Mar     Mango   19      4.094827586
2021_03_Mar     Kiwi    350     75.43103448

my_fruits = data.frame(read.table("my_fruits.txt", header=TRUE))

my_fruits$YearMonth <- factor(my_fruits$YearMonth, levels = c("2021_03_Mar", "2021_04_Apr", "2021_05_May"))


ggplot(data=my_fruits, aes(x=YearMonth, y=Percentage, fill=Fruit)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label= paste(Fruit, paste(" n=",Frequency,sep="") , paste("(",round(Percentage,2),"%)",sep=""), sep="") ), position = position_stack(vjust=0.5), size = 3.25, fontface = "bold") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Total Fruit Count =", stat(y) , sep=" "), group = YearMonth), stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1, size = 5.0, fontface = "bold") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", angle=0, hjust=0.5, size=15), axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", angle=0, hjust=0.5, size=10), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=15)) + 
  labs(y = "% of Fruits")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `facet_wrap`.

1. Modify the dataframe: calculate the count by `YearMonth` and create a column for labelling the facets later
2. Create a named vector for changing the labels of the facet with `labeller`

```
library(tidyverse)

# modify dataframe for later use
my_fruits <- my_fruits %>% 
  group_by(YearMonth) %>% 
  mutate(SumFruits = sum(Frequency)) %>% 
  mutate(label_sum = paste("Total Fruit Count =", SumFruits, sep=" "))

# named vector for changing label of facets
total_count.labs <- c(my_fruits[1,3], my_fruits[4,3], my_fruits[7,3])
names(total_count.labs) <- c("2021_03_Mar", "2021_04_Apr", "2021_05_May")


ggplot(data=my_fruits, aes(x = YearMonth, y=Percentage, fill=Fruit, group=1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label= paste(Fruit, paste(" n=",Frequency,sep="") , paste("(",round(Percentage,2),"%)",sep=""), sep="") ), position = position_stack(vjust=0.5), size = 3.25, fontface = "bold") + 
  facet_wrap(.~ label_sum, scales="free_x", labeller = labeller(total_count.labs)) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, color = "red", face = "bold.italic"),
        legend.position = "none", axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", angle=0, hjust=0.5, size=15), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", angle=0, hjust=0.5, size=10), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=15)
  ) + 
  labs(y = "% of Fruits")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @TaeJae for the solution. The only problem i see with this approach is that, the order of the months gets changed . I wanted the order of months to be "2021_03_Mar", "2021_04_Apr", "2021_05_May". But this plot changes the order based on the facet label "Total Fruit Count = ", and it messes up the months order